# Create a Motorcycle configurator in Microsoft Dynamic CRM Online

Tags: dynamics-crm, external-application

I am trying to find a better solution for a Motorcycle Shop. I like the idea to use Microsoft Dynamic CRM for customer loyalty, that is a good idea but in the other hand I have the Motorcycle Configurator where you can configure the motorcycle as you want. Select version, color, etc.

My idea is to make an external solution because I need to consume data from many sources and sincerely  is not the crm function to configure a motorcycle. Someone has worked with something similar that can enlighten me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usualy such tasks are solved following way:
1. There is separate tool (software) with a good interface to configure car, complex equipment or something else. Such tools provides interfaces and configurations rules and validation (there are options which can exclude each other and so on)
2. This tool is integrated with Dynamics CRM and creates order or quote lines. Each line is either product or option. So crm is not responsible for validation o configuration.

So first of all I can propose to investigate what options you current configurator provides to integrate with it.

Comment: Thank you Marat, Now i will go to investigate and make some proposals. Regards

Comment: These tools are usually called Configure Price Quote tools. If you do a Bing search for Dynamics CRM CPQ you'll find a number of options.